# Connecting Android phone to a mac on network with name.local not IP

Tags: android, networking, localhost

I'm trying to do some local web dev/testing and connect from my `FroYo` Android device to my mac via it's 'name.local' address on the network, rather than via it's IP.

Is this possible? My device refuses to connect, but works with IP.

I have to use name.local due to the nature of the site I'm developing - the domain name has to remain static.